# emacs-ycmd flycheck integration doesn't support C++11

Tags: company-mode, flycheck

I have successfully configured Company-ycmd and ycmd as my C/C++ auto completion engine. It works great but the Flycheck-ycmd seems not support the C++11 syntax.

And it give the following errors:

> Such as: "nullptr is not compatible with c++98"

Comment: It's probably the underlying checker and not flycheck.

Comment: So what's the question? This is not the place to report bugs, if that is what you mean to do. To do that: `M-x report-emacs-bug` or contact the `flycheck` or `company-mode` author/maintainer directly.

Answer (score 3):

I remove `-Wc++98-compat` flag in my `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file and the errors disappeared. And I also suggest to use https://github.com/rdnetto/YCM-Generator to generate  `.ycm_extra_conf.py` file for your project.